# how can I exclude libc from my bare metal arm compilation?

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m, bare-metal

I am trying to compile my first bare metal project targeting an arm cortex-M0+ MCU. I am compiling with gcc arm-none-eabi. The system currently consists of:

- `boot.s` -- an assembly file containing interrupt handlers & vector table. calls SystemInit() then __main()
- `system.c` -- a c file containing chip initialization code `SystemInit()` and `__main()`
- `main.c` -- a c file which blinks some gpio pins
- `cortexm0p.ld` -- a linker script for absolute positioning of code & entry point

The c files are compiled with the flags: `-mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -nostartfiles -nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -ffreestanding -lnosys`
the object files are then linked together with `arm-none-eabi-ld boot.o system.o main.o -T cortexm0p.ld -o blink.elf`

This results in an error:`arm-none-eabi-ld: cannot find libc.a`

Why is my linker command looking for libc? / What do I need to change to make it stop?

Comment: libc can contain support functions that the compiler needs. Which compiler system are you using? If you add `-lc` and look into the map file, what modules are linked into the executable? (Note: You need an option to let the linker generate the map file.)

Comment: looking through some other posts and actually reading my linker script I've come to the conclusion that
`    /DISCARD/ :
    {
        libc.a (*)
        libm.a (*)
        libgcc.a (*)
    }
` 
was causing this issue

Comment: Anything compiled with gcc must be linked with at least libgcc.  There is intentionally no option to tell gcc that it is not allowed to use libgcc.  If your code doesn't use anything from there, then nothing from it will be included in the output.

Comment: You can define the libgcc.a exports with your own versions of the functions. But often not worth it.

Comment: note: not all of those flags are for the compiler, some are for the linker and if you call the two separately you should feed the right ones to each.  but as you figured out that was not the problem. if you control the link, with gnu tools, and depending on the code, you do not necessarily need any of those command line options

Comment: the bootstrap code and the linker script are a intimate marriage you should not mix and match, so if you are creating your own boot.s then you need to create a matching linker script to go with it (less is more).   Likewise for some folks the linker script is related to more of the code than just the bootstrap.  I find less is more, some folks like to grossly overdo the linker script. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

in this case, my linker script file had an explicit discard section excluding libc, libgcc and libm. ::facepalm::